# How to find duplicates in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

I have a list of conference attendees, and I want to make sure the emails are unique.

I could use a countif statement and then sort and delete but looking for other ways and ideas.

Comment: iOS / iCloud / macos version of the app? Might not be a way without scripting or an external tool, but let’s see if you’re OK using the macOS version for this.

Comment: Same here used CountIf myself to do the same if you got something new. Please share.